# Regular expression string followed by numbers

Tags: regex

I am writing a regular expression to extract phrases like `#Question1#` or `#Question125#` from html string like

> Patitent name #Question1#, Patient was suffering from #Question2#, Patient's gender is #Question3#, patient has #Question4# drinking for the last month. His DOB is #Question5#

The first half of the expression is simple just `#Question`, but I also need to match for a series of digits with unspecified length, and the whole string ends with #.

Once I find the matching phrase, how I extract only the digits from the string? Like for example, #Question312#, I just want to get 312 out?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regexp you are looking for is

```
/#Question[0-9]+#/
```

If you need to extract the number you can just wrap the `[0-9]+` part in parenthesis

```
/#Question([0-9]+)#/
```

making it a group. How you use a captured group depends on the specific regexp implementation (e.g. python, perl, javascript ...). For example in python you can replace all those questions with corresponding answers from a list with

```
answers = ["Andrea", "Griffini"]
text = "My first name is #Question1# and my last name is #Question2#"
print re.sub("#Question([0-9]+)#",
             lambda x:answers[int(x.group(1)) - 1],
             text)
```

Comment: Additional question, what if I want to extract just the number from this phrase? thanks

Comment: putting the `[0-9]+` in brackets will make it a numbered capture group. So in `#Question([0-9]+)#`, $1 will hold the number.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is:

`#Question[0-9]+#`

1. #Question
2. Any character in this class: [0-9], one or more repetitions
3. #